# php:Mod rewrite giving me hard times finding base address.. need help

Tags: php, javascript, mod-rewrite, base-address

im new to Mod_rewrite but problem is it ruins all my ajax and php

i use windows.location object to get current location for javascript example:

```
var str = location.pathname;
str=str.slice(0,str.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

problem that this never works since i used mod_rewrite.
my .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/?$ profiles.php?carname=$1 [L]
```

can some body lead me to way to fix this. ?
also i face same problem with lading all imgs and css/.js but i heard i can write condition on .htaccess to only redirect .php !,

I need a way to find base address for ajax calls, and other way to find base address for php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you are redirecting all your url to a php file and it breaks all the other assets, including css and js.

**Solution:**

Use a rewrite condition. this way it only redirects if the file or directory doesn't exist.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^cars/([^/]+)/?$ profiles.php?carname=$1 [L]
```

the first line is : **if file doesn't exist**
the second is: **if directory doesn't exist**
the there will be a redirect.